# How to make images vertical-align to top in Chrome?

Tags: html, css

How to make all images vertical-align to top in Chrome??
It is work on IE,Firefox but it doesn't work on Chrome.

```
<span style="vertical-align:top;"><img src="01.jpg" height="100"/></span><span style="vertical-align:top;"><img src="02.jpg" height="100"/></span><span style="vertical-align:top;"><img src="03.jpg" height="200"/></span>
```

Comment: need Way more information than this.. also why are you not using divs?

Comment: Provide a working example in http://jsfiddle.net. What doesn't work?

Comment: http://doctype.com/ - just to note, generally design inquiries like this can be better answered here.

Comment: I add vertical-align into img and it works, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

```
<style>
img {
  vertical-align:top;
}
</style>
```